# parseInt javascript function

Tags: c#, php, javascript

I am having a JavaScript (.js) file which is used in a PHP project & ASP.Net c# project.

I have some statements in javascript like

```
 var width = data[i].Width - data[i].X;
```

This line works as-it-is in my c# project. But in my PHP project, it has to be written as

```
 var width = parseInt(data[i].Width) - parseInt(data[i].X);
```

Please note that data object is returned as JSON result in both projects.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Are you sure that they are present as numbers in your JSON in both cases, or does it get wrapped in double-quotes by PHP perhaps, turning them into strings, thus causing the need to parse them?

Comment: That just doesn't make sense on soo many levels: the second line of code is JS, not PHP, and is syntactically incorrect. But most likely you need the `parseInt` because the data has some trailing spaces or other chars. Also, be weary of leading zeroes and `parseInt`: always specify the radix: `parseInt(data[i].Width,10);`

Comment: Javascript is same all the languages. What you need to look for is there an auto conversion in c#? can you tell me what is the type there?

Comment: @polin: the data is passed as a JSON string, the type the data had server-side should be irrelevant

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem :then there should be no need of conversion in php like he is doing there. it should work as it worked in c#

Comment: Note that in javascript, even if `data[i].Width` and `data[i].X` are strings, the use of the [subtraction operator](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.2) `-` will coerce them to Numbers, there should be no need for `parseInt`.

Comment: @polin: The only way types can cause this, AFAIK, is that the `Width` value, for example, is extracted from a string like `123px;` and the OP didn't cast (`$data[0]['Width'] = (int) $widthString;`... so come to think of it, yes, you might be right there :) my bad

Comment: @RobG: yes, but if one of the two strings happens to be `123px`, it'll be coerced to `NaN`

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem—if that were so, the first wouldn't work.

Comment: @RobG: the first example comes from C#, which wouldn't permit an assignment of a string (`123px`) to an `int` type. PHP does allow that, which could explain the difference between the two

Comment: Hi All.. thank you for this detailed discussion. I think the issue is PHP could be returning everything as string. Whereas c# returns in specific datatype already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe C# generates a JSON response for `data[i].Width` as `"420"`

While PHP generates `data[i].Width` as `"'420'"`

If you see what I mean?